# How to change date format?

Tags: jquery

I have date in sting object in following format.

dd/mm/yyyy

I want to change it in mm/dd/yyyy in jquery.

any suggestions?

would be grateful for help...

Comment: Do you use any jquery plugin to handle the date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
var mydate = 'dd/mm/yyyy'.split('/'),
    newdate = mydate[1]+'/'+mydate[0]+'/'+mydate[2];
```